# How to ignore whitespacing in input boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need your help,

Normally when a user inputs data, how can the code be modified below so as to program it to ignore any whitespacing, i.e. "a blank keyboard space" ?

Here is the HTML markup in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            $("#fileno").bind("input", function(e) {
                $('#save').prop('disabled', false)
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="save" id="save" disabled>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please define 'ignore whitespace'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Trim function

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp

fieldName = element.property.Trim()

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a pattern attribute with regex to check or you can add a simple check in javascript when clicking the button to submit it.

regex pattern like: 
`pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]"`

javascript jquery check like:

`if($('#inputId').text())` this check will not pass if the value is undefined, null or empty string